# ssl_error_bad_cert_domain on https://blog.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, ssl

I'm seeing a `ssl_error_bad_cert_domain` on trying to reach https://blog.stackexchange.com. The certificate seems to originate from `ssl4208.cloudflare.com`

[image]

Found when browsing `https://stackexchange.com/blogs` and clicked on "Stack Exchange Blog" (see below):

[image]

`blog.stackoverflow.com` works over HTTPS as usual.

Tested on two independent internet connections (mobile and wired) to exclude networking issues on my end:

- Win 7 x64, Firefox 34.0 (beta channel)
- Win 7 x64, Chrome 40
- Android 4.2, Chrome browser

On mobile, HTTP version is served unless HTTPS is specifically requested. Firefox refuses to use HTTP when explicitly requested and HTTPS is available, but Chrome can.

Comment: We've alerted CloudFlare and they're looking into this, stand by..

Comment: Confirmed. Also, if you ignore the security warning, it gives a layout without any styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fixed this some time ago: https://blog.stackexchange.com has a valid cert and now redirects to the new home of https://stackoverflow.blog

Answer (score 5):

Progress, kinda:

- `https://blog.stackexchange.com/` now has a working cert, but most browsers render it as a mess anyway due to mixed content.
- `https://blog.stackoverflow.com/` is broken; you said it was working when you reported the issue but we're told that it was never validated for SSL.

We're working on getting SSL working on the `blog.stackoverflow.com`, but we won't really consider the job to be done until the content actually works properly, without mixed content breaking the render, which will take more time than just fixing the certificates.  For the moment, we still recommend using HTTP for the blogs.